# Solve the equation for $\theta$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, projectile-motion

Hi please help me solving this equation for $\theta$. Thanks

$R = \frac{V_0^2}{g}(b\sin^2{\theta} + \sin{2\theta})$

That R, g, b and $V_0$ are constant

Comment: Divide both sides by $\sin^2\theta$ or $\cos^2\theta$

Comment: Expand $\sin2\theta$ and get $\sin\theta(\sin\theta+2\cos\theta)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint  :$$R = \frac{V_0^2}{g}(b\sin^2{\theta} + \sin{2\theta})\\b\sin^2{\theta} + \sin{2\theta}=\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2}\\
b\sin^2{\theta} + 2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}=\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2}\\$$now divide by $\cos^2 {\theta}$ then you have a quadratic equation by $\tan \theta$
$$b\tan^2{\theta} + 2\tan{\theta}=\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2}(\dfrac{1}{\cos^2 {\theta}})\\
b\tan^2{\theta} + 2\tan{\theta}=\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2}({1+\tan^2 {\theta}})$$ finally you will have 
$$(b-\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2})\tan^2\theta+2\tan \theta-\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2}=0\
\tan\theta=\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{4+4(b-\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2})(\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2})}}{2(b-\dfrac{gR}{v_0^2})}\\\\$$